# What does 'grave injustice' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've encountered the phrase and looked up online, but didn't find a good answer. They ([link1](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090223152417AAWDtZF) [link2](http://brainly.com/question/9701)) were basically saying it's a unjust matter, without explaining the exact connotation and what does 'grave' mean in this phrase.

Comment: [Grave](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grave#Adjective) = serious

Comment: @NS.X. It's great you did some research on the internet before asking your question. But did you also look up the words in a good dictionary? A good dictionary will supply the meaning for each word. In addition, the sites that you link to are **not reliable sources of information**.

Comment: @CarSmack I should have mentioned that I did check with a few online dictionaries (e.g. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grave) which don't have meaning for this particular phrase. I saw the meaning for the word 'grave' but since I haven't learned any other phrases in which 'grave' uses that meaning, I asked this question. The dictionary entry may be sufficient for you or general Indo-European language speakers to understand the phrase with confidence, but not for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close to being a dictionary question. Wiktionary gives this relevant definition for "grave":

> Serious, in a negative sense; important, formidable. [from 19th c.]

This pretty much covers it. However, what the dictionary doesn't say is that this is a "sticky" adjective. (I'm sure there's a more technical grammar term for it, but I don't know it).

What that means is that you will almost always hear "grave" used to modify a small number of words, notably "injustice" or "insult" or "error." They are not quite set phrases or cliches, but they have "stuck" together.

So while you will never hear a native speaker say:

> I had a grave realization this morning.

and you would be unlikely to hear even something like:

> Gather round; I'm afraid I have grave news.

you might well hear someone say:

> The lack of celery in your beef jerky is a grave injustice to vegetarians.

Comment: Excellent point!  I wonder if we should point out that this definition of "grave" has fallen out of common usage outside of these phrases, and even these phrases are becoming rare.

Comment: Wiktionary has a really, really, really wrong date.  In *Hamlet*, written around 1601 the mortally wounded  Mercutio makes a pun on the word, "Ask for me tomorrow, and you shall find me a grave man."

Comment: @Malvolio - You mean _Romeo and Juliet_!

Comment: @KateBunting — haha, of course I did.  Funny how the mind works.

Answer (score 0):

It means injustice, which is so serious or great that it is a cause for concern or worry.